# VHDL timer that returns 1 when it has reached its count

Tags: generics, timer, counter, vhdl, intel-fpga

I'm trying to design a traffic light controller and for this I need a number of different timers. Thus, I designed this generic timer in VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all, IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity timer is
generic (n: NATURAL :=20);
    port (clk, reset : in std_logic;
            count : buffer std_logic);
end entity timer;


architecture behavioural of timer is
begin
    o0: process (clk, reset) IS
    variable cnt : unsigned (n-1 downto 0);
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            cnt := (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            cnt := cnt + 1;
        end if;
        if cnt = n-1 then
            count <= '1';
        else
            count <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behavioural;
```

However, when I run the timer it outputs 0 and never changes (I've tested this by mapping count to an LED on an Altera MAX II EMP240T100C5) and thus the states in my controller don't progress. I have no idea why this happens?

Comment: If you fix this per David's suggestion and map to LED as you suggest above, then the LED will only lit for 1 clock once every 2**n-1 clocks and it is unlikely you will see the LED on.  It will be on so briefly that it will be a very low intensity if at all.

Comment: @JimLewis Thanks, is there a way to make it sit on the value of 1 until it is reset? I really need to counter to stop after it has counted to the number specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `n` is the number of bits in `cnt`, this:

```
    if cnt = n-1 then
        count <= '1';
```

Should be:

```
    if cnt = 2**n-1 then
        count <= '1';
```

`count` is only '1' for one clock.  Did you blink and miss it?  You didn't specify clock rate.  I set clk to 25 MHz for purposes of demonstrating the counter.

This is with the correction above and `n` set to `3` so it would fit in a short waveform display:

[image: enter timer with n equal 3]

Without the above correction the `count` 'pulse' would have occurred after 19 clocks.  Why your traffic light controller didn't respond to it is another question.

### Making count sticky

After your comment stating you wanted to use the timer as a 19 clock delay and you asked Jim how to latch count.

Assuming `n-1` is the trigger value for `count`:

```
    elsif rising_edge(clk) and cnt /= n-1 then
        cnt := cnt + 1;
    end if;
```

This essentially uses the same `n` wide gate output as `count` with an inverter to provide and enable to the `cnt` counter.  It will only get out of the latched trigger value for `cnt` by `reset`.

And why is `cnt` specified as an `n` bit value in it's declaration when it only needs to be 5 bits long in this case?

Are you planning on supplying a trigger count separately for generalizing your timer?  In which case I'd suspect a synchronous reset would in order.

### The simplest overall solution might be to -

Make cnt and integer type:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity timer is
    generic (
        trigger_cnt:    natural := 19
    );
    port (
        clk:        in      std_logic;
        reset:      in      std_logic;
        count:      buffer  std_logic
    );
end entity timer;


architecture behavioural of timer is

begin
o0: process (clk, reset) IS
    variable cnt : natural range 0 to trigger_cnt;
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            cnt := 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) and count = '0' then
            cnt := cnt + 1;
        end if;
        if cnt = trigger_cnt then
            count <= '1';
        else
            count <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_timer is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_timer is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal count:   std_logic;
begin 

DUT:  
    entity work.timer
    generic map (
        trigger_cnt =>  7
    )
    port map (
    clk => clk,
    reset => reset,
    count => count
    );

CLOCK:
    process

    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 360 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULUS:
    process 
    begin
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 40 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Note this has the sticky `count`:

[image: timer with integer type trigger count]

Instead of `n` as a generic a value `trigger_cnt` (compatible with an integer type) is presented as a generic.

In the process `trigger_cnt` is used to limit the range of `cnt` which will get you a synthesized counter of the right number of bits.

Because the counter stops until reset you don't have any pesky errors based on an integer type `cnt` exceeding it's range.

This will only work for a trigger count that falls within the VHDL implementation's integer range (natural range shown here, `subtype NATURAL is INTEGER range 0 to INTEGER'HIGH;` where INTEGER'HIGH is implementation defined and at least 2**31-1 (+2147483647, See Predefined integer types, IEEE Std 1076).

Comment: Thanks. However, the intention is for the 'pulse' to occur after 19 clocks as it needs to trigger a change in the traffic light controller after n number of clock ticks. So does this mean that the code should be working as-is?

Comment: Thanks, I've written that up and I'll test it shortly :). The reason its specified as 'n' bit value is because the timer needs to count to different sizes (e.g. at one point it's initialised as 'timer3 : timer generic map (n => 3) port map(clk,reset3,count3);') and I assumed that was how I'd make the number it counts to variable?

Comment: I'd suggest either algorithmically (a function) relating the size of counter (`cnt`) to the trigger value and just provide it, or provide two generics.  A count of 19 fits in a 5 bit counter while `(n-1 downto 0)` is 20 bits.  A function could march up powers of 2 until it surpasses a trigger count (which wouldn't need to be a power of 2), providing the left value for the range of `cnt`.

Comment: Thanks, that works :). I assume this method is more efficient then my `(n-1 downto 0)` assigment?

Comment: Making cnt just big enough with an unsigned cnt implementation it will be somewhat more efficient, not traversing bits you don't use for the + 1 operation.  They'd naturally get pared during synthesis (producing warnings).  Using a natural (integer) cnt is the most efficient. Instead of a function "+" with a loop traversing 'bits', it's a single operation for integer "+".  When using a natural cnt the range tells synthesis how many bits to use.